# @Autowired variable is null when method in @Controller is final method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my Controller, I have a method like below:

```
@Autowired
StatisticsService statisticsService;

@GetMapping("statistic")
public final WebResponse<List<TierCpStatisticsDataDTO>> getStatisticsInfo(String var) {statisticsService.methodA();  ... ...)
```

With the 'final', statisticsService is null. statisticsService get the correct instance when I remove 'final'.

Can anybody explain why this happens?

Something wired is, when final exists, the controller is proxied like below:
[image]

But after I remove final, the controller is not proxied.

Comment: Because you have something that creates an AOP proxy for that class, and as `final` methods cannot be intercepted they operate on an empty proxy instead of being passed through to the actual embedded object.

Comment: Agree. But I'm not sure when and where the AOP proxy created. The controller and service instances are not proxy.@M.Deinum

Comment: The controller is being proxied, that is why you see `null`... Because you are looking at the proxy NOT the actual instance of the controller. You where asking why is this happening, NOT why is a proxy being created.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. I added some details. The problem is, when I remove final, the controller is not proxied

Comment: It still is being proxied BUT because the method can be intercepted it will pass on to the actual controller INSIDE the proxy. If you check the callstack you will still see the proxy (the classname won't help you here because you are now inside the actual controller and not the proxy).

Comment: The final field is not necessary. It was a typo. But I would like to find out why this happens

Comment: Thanks. M.Deinum. You are correct :) There is proxy in callstack. That means all @Controller will create a proxy?

Comment: I found the AOP is used by @Validated. After I remove Validated. The final field works.

Comment: @ChaoJiang Do not write the answers inside the question body. Please post your own answer with the solution and accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. I found AOP is used by @Validated. After I remove @Validated. The final method works.

Comment: It isn't a `final` field that is the problem. The problem is the `final` method.

Comment: Yes, I got the same issue in one of my service class. When I removed the final keyword for the method the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use **final** in the field-based injection it is a drawback in field-based injection if you wish to use **final** use setter or constructor based injection final work with them.

reference: https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/